# rails rspec - how to check for a model constant?

Tags: ruby, rspec, constants

How can I do something like:

```
it { should have_constant(:FIXED_LIST) }
```

In my model (active record) I have `FIXED_LIST = 'A String'`

It's not a db attribute or a method and I haven't been able to use `responds_to` or `has_attribute` to test for it (they fail). What can I use the to check for it. - btw I have the shoulda-matchers installed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on David Chelimsky's answer I've got this to work by slightly modifying his code.

In a file spec/support/utilities.rb (or some other in spec/support) you can put:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_constant do |const|
  match do |owner|
    owner.const_defined?(const)
  end
end
```

Note the use of "RSpec::Matchers.define" in stead of "matchers"

This allows to test for constants in your specs, like:

```
 it "should have a fixed list constant" do
    YourModel.should have_constant(:FIXED_LIST)
 end
```

Note the use of "have_constant" in stead of "have_const"

Comment: Thank. I am still not sure why Rspec don't give this out of the box. :)

Comment: [Custom RSpec matcher for checking class for constant, with optional class type and value](https://gist.github.com/rokumatsumoto/d5a76b1031738a5cde2d8dedbfc454a5)

Comment: With the new syntax it would be ```expect(YourModel).to have_constant(: FIXED_LIST)```

Answer (score 11):

It reads a little silly, but:

```
describe MyClass do

  it { should be_const_defined(:VERSION) }

end
```

The reason is that Rspec has "magic" matchers for methods starting with `be_` and `have_`. For example, `it { should have_green_pants }` would assert that the `has_green_pants?` method on the `subject` returns `true`.

In the same fashion, an example such as `it { should be_happy }` would assert that the `happy?` method on the `subject` returns `true`.

So, the example `it { should be_const_defined(:VERSION) }` asserts that `const_defined?(:VERSION)` returns `true`.

Comment: I am using RSpec 2.14.1 and I cant get this to work no matter which way I try. Which (major) version of RSpec did you get this to work with? I always end up with a `NoMethodError ... undefined method `const_defined?'` error.

Comment: Sorry too late @RyanScottLewis, cant edit my comment above. I got it to work as follows: `it { subject.class.should be_const_defined(:MY_CONST) }`. The issue was presumably due to it checking against `subject` instead of the Class.

Comment: If you are `describe`ing your class (without quotes), this should work as prescribed in rspec 3.4.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. Terse, consise one-liner syntax without defining additional matchers

Answer (score 8):

If you want to say `have_constant` you can define a custom matcher for it:

```
matcher :have_constant do |const|
  match do |owner|
    owner.const_defined?(const)
  end
end

MyClass.should have_const(:CONST)
```

If you're trying to use the one-liner syntax, you'll need to make sure the subject is a class (not an instance) or check for it in the matcher:

```
matcher :have_constant do |const|
  match do |owner|
    (owner.is_a?(Class) ? owner : owner.class).const_defined?(const)
  end
end
```

See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers for more info on custom matchers.

HTH,
David

Comment: I tried putting it in spec/support/matchers but I get `undefined method `matcher' for main:Object (NoMethodError)` at line 1 of the matcher code

Comment: I've made [a gist](https://gist.github.com/redconfetti/6356551) for this with the solution I devised.

Answer (score 7):

Another option to simply make sure the constant is defined – not worrying about what it's defined with:

```
it 'has a WHATEVER constant' do
  expect(SomeClass::WHATEVER).not_to be_nil
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A warning to anyone trying to test that constants are defined: If your code *references* an undefined constant while defining a class, then your specs will crash before they get to your test.

This can lead you to believe that

```
expect { FOO }.to_not raise_error
```

is failing to catch the NameError, because you'll get a big stack trace, instead of a nice "expected not to raise error, but raised NameError."

Amidst the huge stack trace, it can be difficult to notice that your test is actually crashing on line 1: requre "spec/spec_helper" because your entire application is failing to load before it gets to your actual test.

This can happen if you have dynamically defined constants, such as is done by ActiveHash::Enum, and you then use them in the definition of another constant. Don't bother testing that they exist, every spec in your app will crash if one of them fails to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
defined? YOUR_MODEL::FIXED_LIST
```

Comment: I tried `it { should defined?(:EMPTY_TABLE) }` but got `undefined method `matches?' for "expression":String`

Comment: What about `should defined?(MODEL_NAME::EMPTY_TABLE)` ?

Comment: it { should defined?(ActivityDetail::EMPTY_TABLE) } gave undefined method `matches?' for "constant":String

Answer (score 1):

In RSpec 2, I was able to get this to work in one line as follows:

`it { subject.class.should be_const_defined(:MY_CONST) }`

That is, check against the class, instead of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

In My model

```
 class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   ROLE_ADMIN = "Administrador"     
 end
```

In My rspec

```
 RSpec.describe Role, type: :model do
  let(:fake_class) { Class.new }

  describe "set constants" do
    before { stub_const("#{described_class}", fake_class) }

    it { expect(described_class::ROLE_ADMIN).to eq("Administrador") }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For ruby `2.1.5` and rspec `3.5.0` I am able to test that constant `SEARCH_CHARS_TO_IGNORE` is defined in the class `DiffAlertsDatatable` as follows:

```
expect(DiffAlertsDatatable.const_defined?(:SEARCH_CHARS_TO_IGNORE)).to eq(true)
```